# Celery & Celery Beat daemons not running tasks

Tags: django, linux, celery, daemon, celerybeat

I've set up the celeryd and celerybeat daemon by following [this guide](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/userguide/daemonizing.html). When the daemons start, everything is marked as ok, however Celery simply doesn't run any of the tasks set in my Django application.

This is my `/etc/default/celeryd` file:

```sh
CELERY_NODES="w1"
CELERY_BIN="/home/millez/myproject/venv/bin/celery"
CELERY_CHDIR="/home/millez/myproject"
CELERY_OPTS="-l info --pool=solo"
CELERYD_LOG_FILE="/var/log/celery/%n%I.log"
CELERYD_PID_FILE="/var/run/celery/%n.pid"
CELERY_CREATE_DIRS=1
```

and this is my `/etc/default/celerybeat`:

```sh
CELERY_BIN="/home/millez/myproject/venv/bin/celery"
CELERYBEAT_CHDIR="/home/millez/myproject"
CELERYBEAT_OPTS="--schedule=/var/run/celery/celerybeat-schedule"
```

If I manually restart the daemons, (`sudo /etc/init.d/celeryd restart` and `sudo /etc/init.d/celerybeat restart`), and then check their statuses, this is the only output I get:

```sh
celeryd (node celery) (pid 2493) is up...
```

Running the actual celery commands manually works fine, e.g `celery -A myproject worker -l info`, it seems to be an issue with the way I've set up the daemons. However, I'm not too Linux savvy, so if anyone happens to be able to see some easy oversight I've made, let me know, this is driving me insane.